# Recently adopted Schipperke mix, question regarding its ACL/CCL surgery

Tags: surgery

My girlfriend and I just recently adopted a schipperke mix from the humane society near us. She's a 5year old(give or take a few years), who had ACL surgery back on 8/22/15. She's in roughly week 6 of recovery now.

She was in foster care for some time during the surgery, and then went on to the humane society. Since we've gotten her, she definitely continues to have a limp, especially after sleeping extended periods of time. I've been doing leg stretches for her on the hip, knee and ankle joints every morning and night, we carry her down stairs, but every morning i let her walk up one batch of stairs(15 stairs).

We've been giving her 30-45 minute walks each day(since monday when we adopted her).

On 10/10/15 I see a note taken saying(this based on what i can read):
 "Rev 6 weeks(assume recovery time), Looking good, a may minimal/mild favoring still, mostly no limp". We are supposed to keep her on strict leash until 10/30/15. Her left lateral stifle has a "bump" which was also noted on 9/17/15 by the foster parents, and it still is present.

I'm mainly concerned as I've never dealt with ACL/CCL surgeries before. She is definitely not wanting to put much weight on the leg, which is what is concerning me. When we lift her up to "dance", she puts a majority of her weight on her good leg(right) and when we try to get her to take a few steps she resists. During walks we are not walking at a fast pace, walking on level ground with some incline, however she definitely limps on the leg and refuses to put any weight on it.

Is this "normal"/expected? I dont want to put her under tooo much stress and cause more harm to that leg, however the humane society indicated that she really didn't have a limp. Is there things we should be doing? should we be forcing her to take 1-2 steps while dancing? Should we be putting heating packs on her knee area to help sooth it?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Normally I would expect your local humane society to offer follow-up veterinary service related to the surgery she received in their care.  Have you contacted them?

Comment: We have a free vet appointment scheduled for the 31st of Oct. These are definitely questions that will be brought up when we go in, however thats about a week away. Wanted to reach out to the community in the mean time to see what people have to say

Comment: Thank you, both, so much!   I work at an animal shelter, and I appreciate your care and live for an injured dog.  I wish you the best!   I'm sure your new family member just needs some time.  I know I did when I had my 3 knee surgeries!